# When a derived class exits scope, does the base members get destroyed?

Tags: c++, destructor, member

I have been wondering a thing and couldn't find any relevant answers (maybe I'm just searching for the wrong things?) for this:

If a derived class exits scope (destructor is then called) will the base class members get destroyed too (even if the destructors are removed?).

The idea I get is that destructors are used to delete any dynamic memory or to close any hooks (files etc...). So if I have a managed member (string for example) will it still get destroyed?

Sorry if the question is stupid or has been answered before!
Best Regards, Erik

Comment: What does "even if the destructors are removed" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, base class constructors are called when an instance of a derived class is destroyed. The one case you need to watch out for is if you `delete` a derived object via a pointer to the base:

```
class B
{
public:
   ~B();
}

class D : public B
{
public:
   ~D();
};

void f()
{
   B* p = new D();
   delete p; // will (probably) not call ~D()
}
```

To make cases like the above work, ~B() must be declared `virtual`.

```
class B
{
public:
   virtual ~B();
};
```

Comment: The comment on `delete p` isn't really very accurate.  In a `delete`, if the static type and the dynamic type are not identical, and the destructor of the static type isn't `virtual`, the behavior is not defined.  In this particular case, the most likely behavior is that `~D()` will not be defined, but in other cases, you may end up corrupting the free state arena, or just about anything else.

Comment: @James That's true, and those sorts of considerations were what motivated me to include the parenthetical "probably" :). I was conflicted on how much nitty-gritty detail to include.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an object gets out of scope its d-tor is being invoked - either the default compiler-provided one or user provided one.

If the object includes a base object (or objects) - all of their d-tors are called in a reversed order of the class inheritance definition order.

Then if you need to de-allocate dynamic memory in one of the base classes, simply make sure to provide a d-tor to deallocate the memory in that class